# Database normalization - 4NF

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have the following relation and I need to normalize it to `4NF`.

[Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inl9x.png)

First I've tried to find all the FD's and MVD's that hold.

```
AB ->> C (MVD)
C -> D (FD)  
D -> E (FD)
ABC -> F (FD)
```

Next, using these dependencies I've managed to find the candidate key: `ABC`.
Let me know if what I've done so far is right. Also, is it ok to have a multivalued dependency in 4NF? Like `AB ->> C` and  `ABC -> F`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you normalizing that value, or a variable that holds that value? If a variable then one value can only tell us about FDs & MVDs that don't hold, not ones that do hold--unless we were told that the value was specially designed. Also when a FD holds certain other FDs & MVDs hold. Also we need to know all FDs that hold to know the CKs, so if we are given some but not all FDs & are expected to get the CKs then we must have been told that the FDs form a *cover*.  Etc. Maybe you can see why for homework one should give the exact assignment & show all steps of work following & quoting a textbook.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Only use an image to augment text or to give what text cannot. Only use a link to augment text & images; make your question self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

In general dependencies describe important constraints on the data, for instance a functional dependency `X → A` means that a certain value of `X`  determines uniquely a certain value of `A` (that is, each time we find in a tuple a certain value of `X`, we always find the same value of `A`). Such kinds of constraints cannot be inferred by (few) rows of a table, in which is unknown the meaning of the data.

At the best, we can infer a set of *possible* functional dependencies holding in that *particular* instance of the table, hoping (but without any particular reason) that those functional dependencies will hold on every instance of the table, which is the only condition for which we can “normalize” the relation (and not simply find a non-redundant way of storing a particular instance of that table).

In your case, for instance, since the table has very few rows, many functional dependencies could be seen as holding in it, for instance at least the following:

```
F → AB
E → AD
D → AE
C → ADE
B → A
EF → ABCD
DF → ABCE
CF → ABDE
CB → ADEF
```

(while `ABC → F` can be derived from `CB → ADEF`, and `AB →→ C` does not hold).

And if we should apply a normalization algorithm to that instance (for instance the synthesis algorithm for 3NF), we will decompose the relation in an exaggerate number of subschemas:

```
R1(AB), R2(BCF), R3(CD), R4(ADE), R5(CEF),
```

five relations for a table with six attributes!

Comment: Why AB →→ C doesn't hold? Because for every AB there are more than one corresponding C values.

Comment: If the dependency AB →→ C holds then also AB →→ DEF holds, and the values of DEF should be independent from those of C. But this would mean that for each different value of C with a certain AB, the same AB should have repeated the different values of DEF (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency)).

Comment: Ok, I understand. And another question, if there are more than one candidate keys should I use all of them when performing normalization or just choose one as primary key?

Comment: @Robert, it depends on the algorithm that you are using. For instance for the synthesis algorithm for 3NF, at the end if no relation contains a candidate key of the original relation, than you must add a new relation with one candidate key (any candidate key).